# MongoDB ChangeStream

Tags: mongodb, changestream

I have serval questions for MongoDB ChangeStream(on version 3.6):

- a. When I start a MongoDB ChangeStream at Time T, MongoDB will returned changes on Which timing point?
- b. Will two ChangeStream subscription conflict for the same collection?
- c. Can I use resumeToken on ChangeStream A  to ChangStream B, in order to subscribe the same cursor of the Document changes?

Answer (score 0):

> a. When I start a MongoDB ChangeStream at Time T, MongoDB will returned changes on Which timing point?

See startAtOperationTime description in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.watch/.

> b. Will two ChangeStream subscription conflict for the same collection?

No.

> c. Can I use resumeToken on ChangeStream A to ChangStream B, in order to subscribe the same cursor of the Document changes?

Cursors do not have a "subscribe" operation. You can start a new change stream from the resume token you previously received.

Comment: I mean I  start a new ChangeStream  B from  the resume token I previously received on ChangStream A, at this point, two ChangeStream subscription is still going on, will it ok ?